# Wrapping async MSMQ with a sync WCF service

Tags: wcf, web-services, msmq, messaging

How can I build a synchronous WCF service that wraps asynchronous MSMQ communications?

Let us have a simple scenario. I have a client which supports only synchronous web service calls.  I need to send a synchronous request for "Order", but the back end system exposes this as an asynchronous request and response MSMQs. The WCF does not need to have any logic just wrap the MSMQ asych communication and pass parameters back and forth.

Grateful for your help

Comment: When posting to SO, please include any code you've written in an attempt to solve your problem. We'll help when you show you've done some work already.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I am actually new to WCF and want to validate the concept and whether this valid or not. Some guidance on how to implement it (article or so).. would be great. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Let us have a simple scenario. I have a client which supports only synchronous web service calls
```

Synchronous call means you are using same link (end point url) or channel for your communication between client and server, so according to your assumption no.

Reason: Every time your client will send a request, it will keep waiting for response from server and will produce error.

Alternatively,You can define two services (different end point url) in your wsdl or webservice, one for request and one for response.
At client side you need to invoke these end point url saperately for sending request and receiving response,so it will appear as synchronous but ultimately it will be asynch. Thats all you can do in this scenario.

As per my understanding.